# Tox running fine in one repo clone but not the other

Tags: python, permissions, tox

I tried to run `tox` in a repo clone I have, but got this error:

```
helton@helton-pc /data/Dropbox/Forks do GitHub/fastkml $ sudo tox
GLOB sdist-make: /data/Dropbox/Forks do GitHub/fastkml/setup.py
py27 create: /data/Dropbox/Forks do GitHub/fastkml/.tox/py27
py27 installdeps: pytest, coverage
ERROR: invocation failed (errno 2), args: [local('/data/Dropbox/Forks do GitHub/fastkml/.tox/py27/bin/pip'), 'install', 'pytest', 'coverage'], cwd: /data/Dropbox/Forks do GitHub/fastkml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tox", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cmdline())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/session.py", line 39, in main
    retcode = Session(config).runcommand()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/session.py", line 375, in runcommand
    return self.subcommand_test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/session.py", line 526, in subcommand_test
    if self.setupenv(venv):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/session.py", line 434, in setupenv
    status = venv.update(action=action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/venv.py", line 153, in update
    self.hook.tox_testenv_install_deps(action=action, venv=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluggy.py", line 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluggy.py", line 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluggy.py", line 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pluggy.py", line 596, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/venv.py", line 401, in tox_testenv_install_deps
    venv._install(deps, action=action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/venv.py", line 284, in _install
    action=action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/venv.py", line 257, in run_install_command
    self._pcall(argv, cwd=self.envconfig.config.toxinidir, action=action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/venv.py", line 362, in _pcall
    redirect=redirect, ignore_ret=ignore_ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/session.py", line 136, in popen
    stdout=stdout, stderr=STDOUT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tox/session.py", line 224, in _popen
    stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I cloned the repo to other location, it worked:

```
> cd ~/Desktop
> git clone http://github.com/heltonbiker/fastkml
> cd fastkml
> tox
```

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 64bits with included python 2.7.6 and tox installed with `sudo pip install tox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but the problem is not directly related to tox.

The problem - how trivial it may sound - is, that your projects path contains spaces. The other clone likely did not contain spaces and therefore had no problems:

```
ERROR: invocation failed (errno 2), args: [local('/data/Dropbox/Forks do GitHub/[...]
```

This is a long standing issue with upstream tools like virtualenv and pip. Most of those issues will hopefully be resolved with the release of pip 10 though. See [pip does not support spaces in directories names](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/923)

We also track this in tox here: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/121

Since 2.8 we at least give some more helpful errors, when this happens: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/pull/556